# Making a Javascript a preloader for a HTML Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make a javascript (a javascript animation) as a preloader for a website for my project.

Something along the lines of this:
http://soulwire.github.io/Plasmatic-Isosurface/

I want this to run first and until the elements of my page are downloaded and after that it should turn off and show the completely loaded page

Is this possible?

Thanks

Here's a sample HTML Code I want to test it on

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Javascript preloader</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">  
</head>

<body>
  <div class="preloader"></div>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
    <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/stars_sky_shore_84534_1920x1080.jpg" alt="safe"></img>
</body>
</html>
```

**EDIT TO CODE APOLOGIES

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Preloader Testing</title>
       <style>
      .preloader{
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          z-index: 1000;
      }
      </style>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <canvas class="preloader" id='canvas'></canvas>
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
 <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/stars_sky_shore_84534_1920x1080.jpg" alt="safe"></img>
</body>
<script>
    //after window is loaded completely 
    window.onload = function(){
        //hide the preloader
        document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-custom-preloading-screen/

Comment: That is applicable to a css animation, not a javascript one. Please correct me if I'm wrong (and sorry)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can show the preloader by default. And once the web page is completely loaded, you just hide it. Here is a code sample

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Javascript preloader</title>



      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
      <style>
      /*Styling preloader*/
      .preloader{
          /*
          Making the preloader floating over other elements.
          The preloader is visible by default. 
          */
          position: fixed;
          top: 0;
          left: 0;
          width: 100vw;
          height: 100vh;
          z-index: 1000;
      }
      </style>


</head>

<body>
    <div class="preloader"><span class="preloader-js"></span></div>
  <canvas id='canvas'></canvas>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>

    <img src="https://wallpaperscraft.com/image/stars_sky_shore_84534_1920x1080.jpg" alt="safe"></img>
</body>
<script>
    //after window is loaded completely 
    window.onload = function(){
        //hide the preloader
        document.querySelector(".preloader").style.display = "none";
    }
</script>
</html>
```

Thanks

Comment: Of course, if the preloader takes longer to load than the content, you’ll never see the preload content.

Comment: I've tried doing this, but the thing is the javascript stays on event after I ran your suggestion. The javascript requires very little to load and is very small but it produces a "interactive picture""

Comment: That's true @ScottMarcus, need to make sure the preloader is light weight so that it loads faster.

Comment: Can you please explain what you mean by **the javascript stays on event after I ran your suggestion** ? @ShaunF

Comment: @Obie After a bit of fine tuning I got it to work, Your solution helped tons! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Obie What was happening was, even though the image loaded completely the animation was still playing over it. Now that has been fixed

Answer (score 1):

Put everything you need for your animation in a div with an id and everything you need for your content in another. Give your content `display: none` in your stylesheet. Now you can use `window.onload` to change the styles `document.getElementbyId().style.display = none/inline`

Comment: How do I implement this to a javascript though?

this code produces the animation
  <canvas class="preloader" id='canvas'></canvas>

    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>